# Django Admin site not allowing me to have useranmes with \, even though I overrorde the validator

Tags: validation, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

My site is using Windows Authentication, Which means that when I get users' usernames, they have a \ in them. This also means that I cannot add new users or change existing users via the Django admin site. What I am trying to accomplish is having the usernames allow .

I have tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982521/django-override-asciiusernamevalidator) solution from stack overflow

**My admin.py**

```
class DomainUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = DomainUserChangeForm
    add_form = DomainUserChangeForm


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, DomainUserAdmin)
```

**My Validators.py**

```
class DomainUnicodeUsernameValidator(UnicodeUsernameValidator):
    """Allows \."""
    print2('This is a test')
    regex = r'^[\w.@+-\\]+\Z'
    message = _(
        'Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, '
        'numbers, and \/@/./+/-/_\ characters.'
    )
    flags = 0
```

**My models.py**

```
class DomainUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._meta.get_field('username').validators = [DomainUnicodeUsernameValidator]

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**my forms.py**

```
class DomainUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=150, validators=[DomainUnicodeUsernameValidator])
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = DomainUser
        help_texts = {
            'username': _('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and \/@/./+/-//_ only.'),  # NOQA
        }
```

This is basically an exact copy of the other solution, (I am going to change it to add uniqueness when it is working). Am I missing anything, or do I need to change anything? When I try and change a user in admin, it still says `Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, numbers, and @/./+/-/_ characters.`, but I need that to include .

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well If anyone is looking for this, my solution was to just add username as a readonly field within admin.py. That way it does not get validated, and since I am using windows Auth, Users shouldn't be able to edit their username anyway.

`readonly_fields = ('username', 'password', )`